# My bind_rows is throwing an usual error Can't combine `..1$Activity ID` <logical> and `..2$Activity ID` <factor<2585d>>

Tags: r, dplyr

My code is as shown below and has been running fine for months:

The first part is appending data to dfCampaignTask and this is running fine

```
for (i in files) {
  if (startsWith(i, "CampaignTaskReport_2")) {
    temp <- read.csv(paste(directory, i, sep = ""), header = TRUE)
    names(temp) <- names(dfCampaignTask)
    dfCampaignTask <- rbind(dfCampaignTask, temp)
  }
  else if (startsWith(i, "CombinedReport_2")) {
    temp <- read.csv(paste(directory, i, sep = ""), header = TRUE)
    if (ncol(temp) < 19) {
      names(temp) <- dfCombinedNamesOld
    }
    else {
      names(temp) <- names(dfCombined)
    }
    dfCombined <- bind_rows(dfCombined, temp)
  }
}
```

The second part which is appending data to dfcombined is throwing an error: Can't combine `..1$Activity ID`  and `..2$Activity ID` <factor<2585d>>.

I checked str of all combined files in the folder and activity ID column is all factor so not sure what's causing the discrepancy

Comment: As the error suggests, in the first dataframe you are combining `Activity ID` is a logical variable, whereas in the second dataframe it's a `factor`. You should change them to the same type (I suggest character so that you have no discrepancy in the factor levels) and then use `bind_rows`

Comment: I checked the str of the first dataframe and it was factor too. Not sure where the logical variable is coming from

Comment: Can you share some sample data of your dataset using `dput`? Otherwise it will be difficult to establish what causes the error

Comment: Hi, i have posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565529/bind-rows-is-throwing-an-error-cant-combine-1-activity-id-and-2activity-i

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't