# bind_rows is throwing an error - can't combine 1.activity.id and `..2$activity ID` <factor<2585

Tags: r, dplyr

My code is like this

```
 if (startsWith(i, "CombinedReport_2")) {
    temp1 <- read.csv(paste(directory, i, sep = ""), header = TRUE)
    if (ncol(temp1) < 19) {
      names(temp1) <- dfCombinedNamesOld
    }
    else {
      names(temp1) <- names(dfCombined)    `dfcombined and fdcombinedold are empty dataframes with headers
    }
    dfCombined <- bind_rows(dfCombined,temp1)
 }}
```

This is strange because i have about 11 files in the directory that it's trying to merge into dfCombined and the structure for all of them is like this:

```
'data.frame':   7681 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ ï..Activity.ID         : Factor w/ 2938 levels "CBCC-1E1EELE",..: 23 23 23 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 ...
 $ Type                   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Attendee List",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Activity.Subtype       : Factor w/ 14 levels "1.  IMW â\200“ Introduction",..: 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Created.Date           : Factor w/ 2936 levels "2019-01-01 23:27:54",..: 23 23 23 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
 $ Due.Date               : Factor w/ 83 levels "2019-08-01 00:00:00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Modified.By            : Factor w/ 55 levels "imrankhan","imrankhan",..: 10 10 10 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 ...
 $ Modified               : Factor w/ 2851 levels "2019-06-27 11:35:59",..: 538 538 538 331 331 331 331 331 331 331 ...
 $ Completed.Date         : Factor w/ 2001 levels "","2019-06-27 11:35:58",..: 19 19 19 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ Subject                : Factor w/ 1319 levels "$2 Million Opp",..: 1167 1167 1167 644 644 644 644 644 644 644 ...
 $ Fiscal_Quarter         : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Fiscal_Year            : int  2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 ...
 $ Expense.Type           : Factor w/ 12 levels "","Movie",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ Expense.Amount         : num  211 211 211 581 581 ...
 $ Cost.per.Contact       : num  52.8 52.8 52.8 23.2 23.2 ...
 $ Contact.ID             : Factor w/ 4705 levels "CBCC-1E1EELE",..: 2032 2825 3365 77 334 1018 1406 1593 2350 2430 ...
 $ Full.Name              : Factor w/ 4676 levels "Alex Khong",..: 4073 2896 3979 142 3587 1695 115 2798 280 3942 ...
 $ Branch                 : Factor w/ 1705 levels "","100 MILE HOUSE-9962-001041",..: 353 363 353 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 ...
 $ Primary Code: Factor w/ 3406 levels "","-","7584-0858",..: 2239 1 1 1 1 1 980 973 983 982 ...
 $ Sub.Region             : Factor w/ 38 levels "CF","DR","EC51",..: 31 31 31 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

Why is bind_rows throwing an error ```Error: Can't combine `..1$Activity ID`  and `..2$Activity ID` <factor<2585d>>.

Comment: Can you convert the columns that are factor to character.

Comment: I tried something like this, bind_rows(mutate_all(dfCombined, as.character), mutate_all(temp1, as.character)). The error it threw was Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

Comment: Try `dfCombined %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))`

Comment: Would the expression be temp1<-temp1 %>% (mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)))
+    dfcombined<-bind_rows(dfCombined,temp1)

Comment: Please check if the first expression works or not `temp1 <- temp1 %>% .`

Comment: Throws an error: Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Comment: It works with `iris` `iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))`. I am using `dplyr 1.0.0`

Comment: Tried this  temp1<-temp1%>%
  dplyr::mutate(mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)))
  dfCombined <- bind_rows(dfCombined, temp1)  and it's still giving me this error Error: Can't combine `..1$Activity ID` <logical> and `..2$Activity ID` <character>. Sigh. Not sure what's causing it. How can i install dplyr 1.0.0? could be a version issue?

Comment: Your code is not the same as I showed.  You have couple of `mutate` `dplyr::mutate(mutate(`

Comment: Thanks - Now it is temp1<-temp1%>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)). Is there another phrasing error, still causing the issue

Comment: the across is from the new version of dplyr.  Do you have 1.0.0

Comment: packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.0’

Comment: so when i do str of temp1, it does show every column that was factor as chr. So i think the code works! But its still showing Error: Can't combine `..1$Activity ID` <logical> and `..2$Activity ID` <character> as error

Comment: I am trying to understand how you are reading the data.  Is it a for loop or lapply or map

Comment: What is `i` here?

Comment: for loop! and i is a file   ====   files <-
  list.files(
    path = directory,
    pattern = "*.csv",
    full.names = FALSE,
    recursive = FALSE
  )
for (i in files) {

Comment: can you try the code on my solution post

Comment: As there is only a part of the code showed, there could be some issues in my code.  can you please test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216604/discussion-between-piccinin1992-and-akrun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While inflexible, i went ahead with rbind which solved the problem for now. Still not able to figure out what caused Bind_rows to fail.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to do with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)     
files <- list.files( path = directory, pattern = "*.csv", 
            full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE )
files1 <- files[startsWith(files, "CombinedReport_2")]
out <- map_dfr(files1, read_csv)
```

---

If we need to create a condition for naming

```
out <- map_dfr(files, ~
                       { 
                       temp <- read_csv(.x)
                       names(temp) <- if(ncol(temp) < 19) {
                                      dfCombinedNamesOld
                                  } else names(dfCombined)
                         temp
                          })
```

Comment: Not sure why this is causing an error file does not exist in the current working directory when the directory and files and files1 are picking up the required path and csv fine

Comment: @Piccinin1992. What is the output of `head(files)`

Comment: @Piccinin1992 Try with `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`

Comment: for some reason, your code is calling a working directory. Why is it doing that? no wonder its not picking up the files

Comment: @Piccinin1992 what is the output of `head(files)`. can you check what is the value of `directory`

Comment: head(files) 
[1] "Branch_Extract.csv"            "CampaignTaskReport_2018Q1.csv" "CampaignTaskReport_2018Q2.csv"
[4] "CampaignTaskReport_2018Q3.csv" "CampaignTaskReport_2018Q4.csv" "CampaignTaskReport_2019Q1.csv"
and this is what i want and directory is the path in question

Comment: @Piccinin1992 that is the issue.  I have changed to `full.names = TRUE` then the full path will be there

Comment: @Piccinin1992 try running it once more `files <- list.files( path = directory, pattern = "*.csv", 
            full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE )` and get the `head(files)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216606/discussion-between-piccinin1992-and-akrun).